# chronic gives me error after installation (ruby)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

- I run ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11
  patchlevel 287) [i386-mswin32]
- I had to upgrade RubyGems so I run
  1.3.5 now
- then I istalled chronic (0.2.3)

but I only receive

```
./chronic.rb:3: uninitialized constant Chronic (NameError)
    from E:/prog/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from E:/prog/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from chronic.rb:1
```

if I run this code

```
require 'chronic'

puts Chronic.parse("yesterday")

puts "Tomorrow = #{Chronic.parse('tomorrow')}"

puts "Today = #{Chronic.parse('today')}"

puts "yesteday = #{Chronic.parse('yesteday')}"

puts "2 days ago = #{Chronic.parse('2 days ago')}"

puts "2 months ago = #{Chronic.parse('2 months ago')}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the file that contains your test code named `chronic.rb` or is there another file in the current directory named `chronic.rb`? If so, try renaming it.

Your `require 'chronic'` statement is loading the file `chronic.rb` from the current directory rather than searching for the file in the gem.

Comment: @Phil Ross: I'm bit blushing now :-) it is working now.Thank you...and again I learnt something new....